# Unexpected slow speeds with my ISP when connecting to websites hosted in other countries

Tags: networking, vpn, internet, routing, isp

My ISP have this strange problem. It works good on sites hosted on servers in my country, but is miserable when it comes to internationally hosted websites esp during day time. Other ISPs available here don't the have same problem. Also I noticed a strange anomaly if I use a VPN.

Here are speed benchmark on single connection.

My ISP -> Large file  (In other country) = ~1 Mbps

My ISP -> L2TP/IPSEC VPN (in same country) -> Large file (In other country) = ~1 Mbps

VPS (same one containing L2TP/IPSEC server) -> Large File (using `wget` after SSH) = 10-50 Mbps.

My ISP -> VPS (Downloading the file I just downloaded on VPS) = 10 Mbps.

So as you can see, I get 1 Mbps speed when I access the file hosted in another country or far away. But if I download it on VPS and download it from there, I get 10 Mbps speed. Even if I count the time to download file on VPS first, the average will be 5 Mbps which is way higher than the other case.

I am wondering what is the problem with my ISP. I own the VPS server so I can install pretty much anything there. Is there any way to use VPS to solve this ISP issue.

I don't want to download first on VPS and then download it from there all the time (It's not feasible if you are just surfing internet in web browser). So any other solution is really appreciated.

The issue happens with other devices in my home too. So it's just not my computer.

Comment: Please do some `pathping`s so we can see what is going on.

Comment: @DavidPostill Here it is. https://gist.github.com/VarunAgw/39f852a4c17ffff39b6e5dad412c99f2

Comment: We need a pathping or equivalent to a source outside the country both with and without VPN turned on. The idea is to check if traffic is going via the VPN when its up.

Comment: Hmm. Some small packet loss at your ISP and vsnl.net.in but not enough to account for such a big speed difference. You should talk to your ISP and let them investigate.

Comment: @DavidPostill Unfortunately that's not possible. There is only one ISP in my town (except mobile internet) and the owner is kind of prick. He is impossible to deal with. So I am trying to solve the issue myself.

Comment: Please do what DavidGo suggested above ...

Comment: @davidgo Yes. It's going. Updated the link. https://gist.github.com/VarunAgw/39f852a4c17ffff39b6e5dad412c99f2

Comment: @DavidPostill Updated.

Comment: Nothing in there to show any packet loss other than slightly overloaded routers. Nothing to explain the speed difference.

Comment: @DavidPostill - your advice would be appreciated here -  I've posted an answer based on speculation.  What do you think about the likelyhood the issue is MTU?

Comment: @davidgo Not really my area of expertise, but I guess it's possible. No harm in trying your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I can't be certain, but the best I can posit is there are 2 problems - your ISP has limited International bandwidth  and for the alternate path via the VPN you may have MTU/fragmentation issues.

Try reducing the MTU size of the appropriate interface on your computer (Reduce it by 104 bytes initially, if that works, try increasing it back trying increments of 8 bytes until the problem recurs, then set it back).   If you want a stab in the dark that could "fix it in one", try setting the mtu to 1472.

Comment: Thanks. I tried different MTU values. Sadly it didn't work :(